# Removing Both HTML and PHP Extensions

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to remove page extensions and i used this methods:

Method 1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Method 2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

But with these methods I can only remove php extension!
How can i remove both html and php extensions?

Comment: https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 RewriteEngine on

# remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]

#remove .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well :)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ http://your-domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$  http://your-domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For more information see: https://htaccessbook.com/add-remove-change-file-extensions-htaccess/